# useMemo is constant linter warning

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-usememo

This is what I got and it works fine.

```
const loadingList = useMemo(() => [], [])
```

However, I get the warning using Chrome browser saying

> 'loadingList' is constant

When I change it to let, the warning goes away, but I don't understand why it can't be let... seems strange. All the React hooks I use are const.

This is how it's used

```
  function addLoadingProcess(process) {
    loadingList.push(process)
  }

  function clearLoadingProcess() {
    loadingList = []
    setAppIsLoaded(true)
  }

  function removeLoadingProcess(process) {
    const index = loadingList.indexOf(process)
    if (index > -1) {
      loadingList.splice(index, 1)
    }

    if (loadingList.length === 0) {
      setAppIsLoaded(true)
    }
  }
```

It points to this function

```
function clearLoadingProcess() {
  loadingList = []
  setAppIsLoaded(true)
```

}

Comment: Please show where you are using loadingList. This should not be from the declaration

Comment: `loadingList = []` should not done as `loadingList` is const. Try using `loadingList.splice(0,loadingList.length);` which would empty the array and keep the reference of `loadingList` intact.

Comment: In addition to @user1672994's comment, if you want the list change to trigger a rerender please keep it in state

Comment: you shouldn't use `useMemo` for what you are doing, use `useRef` instead, or `useState` if you want to rerender on state change

Answer (score 1):

You can not change the reference of the `const` variable. 
That's why the compiler throw an error

```
 'loadingList' is constant
```

In your case, you have 2 options:

- use let
- change `loadingList = []` to  `loadingList.length = 0`. In this case, we still keep the same reference and you will be able to use `const`.

PS. I do not know why you need to do such things. Your code smells bad. 
Can you explain what you want to achieve with this `loadingList`?

Comment: smells, bad, maybe. ) I send a bunch of WS messages to the back-end to fetch data and need to keep track of them. I add a push a process name to the array for each WS message. As they start coming back I catch each one individually and remove the process from the array. My content is ready to render as soon as the array is empty.

Comment: Maybe you should try to use async / await function and render it once everything will be ready.